# Manipulate my flash depending on a URL?

Tags: django, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs3

I have a flash map of the UK which is divided up into the counties, a user clicks on a county and is then directed to a new url, eg. `www.mydomain.co.uk/region/london`. The flash map remains on that new page in case they wish to select a new region.

What I want to know: is it possible to manipulate the flash so that if the url is `www.mydomain.co.uk/region/london` then london remains highlighted on the flash map. I presume I will have to use some AS which is fine as long as it is AS3.

Comment: What you are looking for is a [sitelock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791352/how-to-site-lock-a-flash-application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with writing your own AS3 scripts.
The method I would use in this case is to fetch the URL of your browser, and to parse the location out of it.

See related question: [How can my Flash app determine its own URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396412/how-can-my-flash-app-determine-its-own-url)

Alternatively you can have the individual county pages pass a variable to the Flash movie in the embed/object tag via the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it using as3 alone would be to get the URL from the stage's loaderInfo object like so:

```
Stage.loaderInfo.url
```

A better but more difficult way to go about it would be to use swfAddress to set up deep linking, history, and other such browser normalities. http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/